# App crashing through iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes

I found crash while I am downloading app from iTunes and tapping on **“Open”** but when I try to open from app icon logo(which is downloaded from iTunes) , its working fine. I would like to know that what is happening and at where I am missing.Thanks in advance

**Edited:** : I found crash only 10 and above iOS vesion and crashing on launch screen.

Comment: You should ask it in another stackexchange site like : [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can use some kind of tool to watch crashes and its log like https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install so you can get easily when that crash and which code line issue

Comment: @NitinGohel I will do, but current one is live and not having crashlytics , but I can't understand that tapping on icon is working fine and through the itunes try to open its crashing .

Comment: its strange :) because that stuff handle by iOS you can check it after add the crashlytics. and test app via Test-flight that act the same like a live build

Comment: @Lion. Thanks. I will do.

Comment: @NitinGohel I tried through Test-flight app is working fine

Comment: does it open from test-flight its working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132063/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-meera).

Answer (score 0):

I released new build on iTunes and the issue is solved.At the end no changes in the code. Its seems may be there is some issue of iTunes.
Thanks to all for help
!